# Dual Booting with windows

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, elementary-os

I am trying to dual booting elementary OS with windows 7. Basically on my 160 GB HDD, i have following partitions:

```
sda1 which is C drive having windows 7.
sda5 which is D drive with data

and an 10 GB unallocated space.
```

Now my question is: Can I install Luna on that 10 GB space? Will both OS work if I allocated that 10GB partition for both OS and boot-loader? Last time I tried to install Luna with Windows, none of the OS loaded on next boot.

I am a novice to this so your help will be appreciated.

Comment: There is a LOT of excellent information and procedures already written and available if you'd just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you certainly can. If it doesn't work just run from some live-cd/usb with linux the [grub-install /dev/sda](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installation.html#Installation) command and you will have both Luna, Windows and any other OS installed in the drive listed in the booting section